# How to manage the order (or dependencies) of entity creation for a module that defines multiple new custom entities

Tags: entities

I have a module I'm building that creates and uses multiple custom entities. For each entity I've created a relevant file, new_module/src/Entity/modulename_entity1.php, new_module/src/Entity/modulename_entity2.php, etc. This seems to be working fine, however I'm running into an issue when trying to create an entity reference field that is on say, modulename_entity2 that references modulename_entity1. For some custom entities contained in this module it works fine to reference another, and for others I get a "modulename_entityX" doesn't exist error when loading the module.

As far as I can tell, it appears it's working if the custom entity being reference, just happened to get loaded/created first, and fails if the entity referencing the other happens to be created before the one being referenced. How does Drupal determine the order it generates the tables and entitles defined by a module, if there is more than one?

Is there a way to dictate this order using the module's configuration files, or the new custom entities annotation? I realize I could create separate modules for each entity and make the referenced entities a dependency, however I'm hoping there is a solution that allows me to manage the order so I can keep them all in one module.